# PHP with HTML - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with this code. I see other questions on this, but continued without find the  mistake.  This code work in other computer, but now is giving me problems in my computer. Here is my code, i hope than help me....

> ```
>         <?PHP 
>         include "conexion.php";
>         $fecha = date('Y-m-j');
>         $ayer = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
>         $ayer = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $ayer );
>         $hacedias = strtotime ( '-8 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
>         $hacedias = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $hacedias );
>         $consulta = "SELECT date_format(fecha,'%d %M') AS FECHA, round((SUM(`TotalMinutos`)/60),1) FROM reporte WHERE  ingeniero ='". $_SESSION['id']."' AND fecha BETWEEN  '$hacedias' AND  '$ayer' GROUP BY fecha";
>         $rs = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
>         if(mysql_num_rows($rs)!=0){
>         ?>
>         <p></p>
>         <p></p>
>         <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100">
>             <tr><?PHP
>                     $i = 0;
>                     while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 
>                     if($i == 8){
>                       echo "</tr><tr>";
>                       $i = 0;
>                     }?>
>                 <td width="100">
>                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="150">
>                       <tr> <td width="80"><B><?=$reg['FECHA']?></B></td>  </tr>
>                       <tr> <td width="80"><?=$reg['round((SUM(`TotalMinutos`)/60),1)']?> Horas</td>  </tr>
>                     </table>
>                 </td>
>                 <?
>                 $i++;
>                 }
>                 ?>
>             </tr>
>             </table>
>             <p>
>             <?PHP 
>                 }else{echo "<h3><p style='color:#FF0000'>ATENCION!!! <br>No has registrado tus tiempos en los ultimos 5 dias.</p></h3>"; }?></table>
> ```

Thank you for you help...

Comment: you are missing a semicolon somewhere. maybe even before the code you posted.

Comment: The parse error message should show you a line number, it's kind of a big deal...

Comment: i hope your first line is not : > <?PHP

Comment: So MUCH **[fine literature on the left](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uhjle.png)** that it hurts

Comment: Use the endif and endwhile will make your code easier to handle. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lost semicolon on `<?=$reg['FECHA']; ?>` and `<?=$reg['round((SUM(`TotalMinutos`)/60),1)']; ?>`

Comment: while it is one of the errors in the OP's code, it wouldn't produce that error, see [http://3v4l.org/HbmmQ](http://3v4l.org/HbmmQ)

Comment: Quite so, missing two semicolon... additional, i don't know why, this code not work when not used the word PHP to start the sentence.. example:

ERROR: <?
OK: <?PHP

Comment: change in your php.ini `short_open_tag = Off` to `short_open_tag = On` then restart your apache... 
look at ['php short_open_tag'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).